# ¿Como escapar el punto "." en el nombre de un atributo (key) de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

estoy trabajando con una integración, la cosa es que al hacer la llamada a la API esta me devueve un JSON donde los nombres de los atributos traen punto:

Ejemplo:

```
{
"com.response-message": {
    "com.header": {
        "com.firstIndex": 0,
        "com.lastIndex": 2
    }
}
}
```

Ahora bien lo que intento hacer es acceder al primer atributo para ir accediendo a los demas, algo como:

```
  const response = epnm.getChassis();
  console.log(response.com.response-message);
```

Pero es no me funciona, de que manera puedo escapar ese punto como para que se detecte como que forma parte del nombre del atributo?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Usa comillas: `console.log( response['com.response-message'] );`

Comment: Gracias amigo :)